# Can't get site root url in asp mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I need to get site root url in razor page in javascript code:

```
...
var siteRootUrl = '@Url.Content("~")';
...
```

But all I get from this is '/'.

Comment: My site root. mysite.com or locahost:4455

Answer (score 61, accepted):

To get the current host with port (mysite.com, www.mysite.com or localhost:9876)

```
 Request.Url.Authority
```

To get your current application folder: (/ or /appfolder/)

```
 Url.Content("~/")
```

To mix them?

```
 String.Format("{0}://{1}{2}",Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.Authority,Url.Content("~/"))
```

OR (As torm pointed out)

```
 Url.Action("", null, null, Request.Url.Scheme)
 Url.Action("", null, null, "http")
 Url.Action("", null, null, "https")
```

To generate an Action URL:

```
 Url.Action("About","Home",null,"http")
```

Comment: Great answer @Splash-X!  I am using your "mix", but I wanted to point out one correction... It's Requst.Url.Scheme (not Schema).

Comment: Seplling was never my strong point. I've updated my typos in the code example. Thanks for the info @bmccleary

Answer (score 8):

Easiest way I know to get AbsoluteUri would be

```
@Url.Action("", null, null, "http")
```

Comment: To be honest with you I never thought of doing it this way, nice touch!

Comment: This will give the controller name as well, if called from within a controller method.

Answer (score 4):

`@Url.Content()` returns the root RELATIVE path, that is the path from the root of the domain.

So if your site was at www.foo.com/site then Url.Content() returns /site

Ishmael's response is correct.  You will need to parse a full url.

Answer (score 2):

The @Url.Content is returning the relative URL which is correct.
The following code gives you various option in getting a URL realtive via code, absolute Url via code, absolute via javascript:

```
<div>Site 'Relative Url = '@Url.Content("~")'</div>
<div>Site 'Absolute Url = '@System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri'</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("site URL via js = " + location.href);
</script>
```

You will get something like:

Site 'Relative Url = '/'
Site 'Absolute Url = 'http://localhost:14763/'

and also the JS alert showing the href/absolute Url

Comment: Your answer just has a minor terminology issue; '/' is actually an "absolute path". The fact that it starts with the slash makes it absolute and rooted. A relative path starts with a name or dots: "../", "Images/Jpg/".

Comment: Yes you are correct, my mistake. :-) I confabulated it with resolving the relative path. :-)

Comment: hehe... no biggie; I had to edit my comment because I made a couple mistakes myself!

Answer (score 0):

For the full URL, use `@Request.Url.ToString()`.

You can either parse that, or use one of the other methods on the `HttpRequest.Url` property, which is a `System.Uri` object.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx