# ASP site root url

Tags: asp.net, url, root, absolute-path

Sorry for question that is already asked few times and on other forums, but I really didn't find a solution that gives what I need.

I have an ASP.NET MVC site. And in one of the controllers I need to find the root url of the site (For example http://myhost:7777/MyVirtualDir/). I need it as is, not any relative urls - only full absolute ROOT url of the site. The reason is that I will use this url from other application to access service, hosted on site.
I tried many dirrerent variants and proposed solutions from other forums, including:

```
VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~") // Returns "/" - it returns relative url
Url.Content("~")  //Returns "/MyVirtualDir/" - only virtual directory path part
```

and all other ToAbsolute return relative paths.

**I invented the following**:

```
Request.Url.ToString().Substring(0, Request.Url.ToString().Length - Request.Url.PathAndQuery.Length + Url.Content("~").Length);
```

*Looks like it works*. But there is too much magic here. *Is there a normal way to retrieve such path*?

Comment: So what was wrong with this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121140/cant-get-site-root-url-in-asp-mvc

Comment: No of the provided solutions there handles virtual directory path

Comment: When I tested with my own url of the form `http://sub.domain.com/virtual/WebPage.aspx`, the code `String.Format("{0}://{1}{2}",Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.Authority,Url.Content("~/"))` returns the exact same result as your code example.  Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Oh, you are talking about that one =). It is not better then mine I think... The same magic

Comment: But it works, and was the accepted answer, so... You could wrap it up in a function and add to your internal business library to abstract it until you find a better solution.

Comment: What do you think I am doing now? I'm searching a better solution having one not elegant. I wrote this in my post.

Comment: Right. I guess I don't think there's really anything better.  The best I could find with more searching was `Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + Request.ApplicationPath`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there is no built-in functionality to grab specifically the root of the application with virtual paths in a single call.  The simplest solution I can find is this:

```
Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + Request.ApplicationPath
```

You may also find this useful: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Dec/21/Making-Sense-of-ASPNET-Paths